# How To Detect CSS within Style Tags PHP

Tags: php, styles, preg-match

I want to detect style tags and the CSS inside the style tag minified (removing all spaces, etc).

```
preg_match("/\<style\>(.*)\<\/style\>/i",$str,$title);
```

That detects it, but some creators use `<style type="text/css">`, how can I also detect those instead of only `<style>`?

Comment: If you plan to use regex you may think of `'~<style(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)text/css\1)?>(.*?)</style>~is'`, but using DOM is always safer.

Comment: Yes, use the DOM.  Checking HTML using regexps is just asking for a security bug.